# HTML Webpack Plugin v5 - templateParameters

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I have a small application written in Webpack using HTML Webpack Plugin: https://github.com/einazare/html-webpack-plugin-18n-generator

And I am trying to use `templateParameters` to pass some variables to my HTML template, and it won't work. I do not know if this is a bug from the plugin, or I am doing something wrong.

I have followed the examples shown:

- Here: https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#writing-your-own-templates
- And here: https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/tree/main/examples/template-parameters

I would like my `<%= title %>` to be replaced with the actual value of my `templateParameters.title` value, i.e. value located inside `locales/de-DE.json` or `locales/en-GB.json`.

I've also tried to modify the `<%= title %>` to `<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.templateParameters.title %>`.

If you want, you can clone the repository and then:

1. Install the dependencies with `npm install`
2. Build the application with `npm run build`
3. Open `dist/index.html` in an editor
4. You will see `<%= title %>` was not replaced by `Some title written in English (Great Britain)`